# JSON convert to C#

Tags: c#, json

Anyone know how to convert this JSON [POSTMAN JSON image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL4Yl.jpg) to C# class, where I want to create a dictionary with key as Date and values with other atributtes.. Online tool convert it like this [Online tool converter JSON to C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBL3n.jpg) but this is not right.

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "2020-08-27": [
        {
            "Duration": 424,
            "End": "13:04",
            "Start": "06:00"
        },
        {
            "Duration": 366,
            "End": "20:00",
            "Start": "13:54"
        }
    ],
    "2020-08-28": [
        {
            "Duration": 427,
            "End": "13:07",
            "Start": "06:00"
        },
        {
            "Duration": 159,
            "End": "20:00",
            "Start": "17:21"
        }
    ],
    "2020-08-31": [
        {
            "Duration": 15,
            "End": "06:15",
            "Start": "06:00"
        },
        {
            "Duration": 111,
            "End": "08:40",
            "Start": "06:49"
        },
        {
            "Duration": 630,
            "End": "20:00",
            "Start": "09:30"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It will help if you edit your question to include the actual Json and not just a picture of it

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/02/paste-json-and-xml-as-class.aspx?

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=osvRg5JanpOKu9Jgzsc7

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<DateTime, ItemObject>>(json)`

Comment: Above is JSON code, and this I try to convert to class file, where date will be key and value will be other informations like duration, end and start.

Comment: Did you click the link I provided @blazk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a json that conforms to a Dictionary of a `DateTime` and a `List<Item>`. You can use the following to deserialize your Json

```
public class Item
{
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
}

// and in main,
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>>>(json);

// Use TryGetValue to look up values of a specific Key 
obj.TryGetValue(DateTime.Parse("8/27/2020"), out List<Item> items);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items.Select(x => x.Duration)));

// prints
424, 366
```